# Corrupted Xamarin.Android.Common.targets file: Errors on _CompileJava

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

A few days ago I tried to build a imported sample project, but this failed due some errors in the `Xamarin.Android.Common.targets` file. By accident I deleted a few too many lines in the file and now I cant seem to deploy my other Xamarin projects which worked before. Deployment fails on:

```
The target "_CompileJava" does not exist in the project.
```

Is there a way to recreate the targets file or to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it myself.

Did the following to fix it:

- Uninstalled Xamarian and all Xamarian / App components using `Visual Studio Installer`
- Manually deleted the Xamarin folder (which also contains the `Xamarin.Android.Common.targets` file) on `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin`
- Deleted all SDK Tools and Platforms in the Android SDK Manager (found in Visual Studio)
- Re-installed Xamarin and all it's components as well as all the SDK platforms and tools.

This did the trick. The Xamarin folder was recreated and I can deploy my solutions once more. 
TIP: If you got the same problem, don't forget to make screenshots of your SDK tools and platforms and installed Xamarian components.